# Convert text to object

Tags: javascript, type-conversion

I have a string, something like this below

```
const UID = "befjbljfbelgvfghvgjhsv";
console.log(typeof(UID), UID);
string befjbljfbelgvfghvgjhsv
```

I have a utility which takes the above string format (a unique ID) but in type `object` format. It needs to be in `object` type and but `string` looking. 
So I want to convert the above `string` to `object` type.

so basically I want some thing like:

```
convertedUID = ???
console.log(typeof(convertedUID), convertedUID);
object befjbljfbelgvfghvgjhsv
```

Any quick hacks?

Comment: The closest you can get is `convertedUID = new Object(UID);` That will print `object String { "befjbljfbelgvfghvgjhsv" }` in the `console.log`.

Comment: Just curious, why do you need this? JavaScript isn't exactly known for its strong typing...

Answer (score 1):

You can think of a wrapper method, let's call it objectify

```js
function objectify(val){
    var obj = {
        toString: function(){
            return val
        },
        valueOf: function(){return val}
    }
    return obj
}
var x= objectify('this_is_a_string');
console.log(typeof(x) + ' ' + x);

// can be used as a key as well
// mostly all operations what work on a string.
var y={};
y[x] = 456;
console.log(y['this_is_a_string']);
```

Don't expect console.log(typeof(x), x); to work like you asked for.
console.log(typeof(x) + ' ' + x); would work as string concatenation would force a coercion.

Answer (score 0):

There is no object like `object befjbljfbelgvfghvgjhsv` in javascript;

object must have a key, value pair (e.g. `{ text: "befjbljfbelgvfghvgjhsv" }`)
and you can convert your string to object by creating a new object, and assigning your string to a key in it; but the `key` name matters, the function you are going to pass that object probably expect a specific key name. 
check the snippet below:

```js
const UID = "befjbljfbelgvfghvgjhsv";
const newObject = { text : "befjbljfbelgvfghvgjhsv" }
console.log(typeof(newObject), newObject.text);
```